# How do I make WebClient.DownloadFile() work with xnb, xgs, xsb, xwb files?

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, webclient

I'm creating an Updater program in C# for my PC game that basically sends an Http message to the server to find out what the latest version of the game is. If there is a newer version, it downloads the necessary files. To download the files I used the WebClient.DownloadFile() method. There are a few posts on the forums detailing problems with this method but none of them are quite like mine.

I use the method like this:

```
WebClient  webClient = new WebClient();<br/>
webClient.DownloadFile(sOriginFile, sDestinationFile);
```

I immediately ran into a problem downloading any files with the following extensions:

```
.xnb
.xgs
.xsb
.xwb
```

I would get an exception stating "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

So as an experiment I added 3, more common, files to the same directory.

```
.txt
.doc
.jpg
```

and the DownloadFile() method worked perfectly for those files. Does anybody know why this method isn't working for the first 4 files types but works fine with the last 3?

Also I tried WebClient.DownloadData() and HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() (after setting up the request), I even tried reversing the extension name on the server (.bnx), but no matter what, I would get the same exact exception.

If anybody really wants to tackle this, here are links to 2 sample files (I tried to post all 7 sample files but Stack Overflow only allows me to post 2 links):

http://www.facepuncher.com/Versions/CastleAbra/1.1/Sample.txt
http://www.facepuncher.com/Versions/CastleAbra/1.1/UiCursor.xnb

Comment: please check your webserver whether the problemtic extensions have registered MIME types with the server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the MIME-Settings for the file types you mention are set up incorrectly in IIS. Go to IIS Server Mananger -> MIME-Settings and add the file-types accordingly.

Probably a better idea to transfer any filetype would be to download only files like

```
file.xnb.dat
file.xgs.dat
```

and rename them locally.

-Matthias

Comment: Thanks! I never knew what MIME settings actually meant. It turns out that .dat was also not set up on the server, so I just went ahead and modified the web.config file to add the 4 extensions I needed. I have it hosted on GoDaddy and their instructions were pretty good. Thanks so much! This was killing me for 2 days!